# ACF Repeater PHP Template for repeated Image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

This is my template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News Page
*/
?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="bio">


        <?php           
            if(have_rows('news_article')):
                while(have_rows('news_article')): the_row();?>

                    <?php if(get_sub_field("image")): ?>
                        <div class="row bottom-margin">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-7">
                                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" class='img-responsive'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row bottom-margin">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <hr class="news-hr">
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    <?php endif; // end of if field_name logic ?>   

                <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php endif;?>  

    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

But when I load the page nothing displays but the header? I have setup the Custom Fields page, there is one repeater: "news_article" and within that one image: "image"?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation for the [ACF Image Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) type. I would check to make sure that your "image" sub field return value is set to "Image URL" with how you are using your code.

[image]

Please let me know if this works for you.